# Где я ошибся? код выдаёт ошибку: f-string: expecting '}' (user_code, line 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import choice
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'a','b','c','t','q']
ticket = [1,5,8,6]
win_ticket=[]
count = 0

while ticket != win_ticket:
    win_ticket = [choice(numbers) for i in range(4)]
    count += 1
print(f"My ticket {"".join(map(str, ticket))} has won")
print(f"It tooks {count} steps")
```

Код выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
  count += 1
              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: проблема в том, что перед `count += 1` у вас 4 пробела, а перед `win_ticket = ` табуляция

Comment: Спасибо, я даже не обратил на это внимание 

Answer (score -1):

```py
from random import choice

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'a','b','c','t','q']
ticket = [1,5,8,6]
win_ticket = []
count = 0

while ticket != win_ticket:
    win_ticket = [choice(numbers) for i in range(4)]
    count += 1
print(f"My ticket {"".join(map(str, ticket))} has won")
print(f"It tooks {count} steps")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: И в чем отличие?